# How to conditionally format JavaFX ComboBoxTableCell label

Tags: javafx, combobox, format, label

I assume it is possible to **conditionally format** JavaFX `ComboBoxTableCell` **label** according to following JavaFX 11 documentation items:

- [ComboBoxTableCell](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html) class description:

> By default, the `ComboBoxTableCell` is rendered as a `Label` when not being edited [...].

- [Labeled](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setTextFill(javafx.scene.paint.Paint)) class `setTextFill` method description:

> Sets the value of the property `textFill`.

If my assumption is correct, I would like to know how to modify following SSCCE so that any `ComboBoxTableCell` label `textFill` property is set to following `Paint` values. Thank you!

1. `Color.Red` if its value is not valid

[image]

2. `Color.Blue` if its value is set for different rows.

[image]

```
public class PersonInRoom extends Application
{
    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob"   , "Kitchen"),
        new Person("Isabella", "Bedroom"),
        new Person("Ethan"   , "Attic"));

    TableView<Person> table ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        TableColumn nameCol = new TableColumn("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));

        TableColumn roomCol = new TableColumn("Room");
        roomCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("room"));
        roomCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("Bathroom", "Bedroom", "Kitchen"));
        roomCol.setOnEditCommit((EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>) t -> t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setRoom(t.getNewValue()));

        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, roomCol);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person
    {
        private final SimpleStringProperty name;
        private final SimpleStringProperty room;
        private Person(String name, String room)
        {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.room = new SimpleStringProperty(room);
        }
        public String getName()         {return name.get();}
        public String getRoom()         {return room.get();}
        public void   setRoom(String r) {room.set(r);}
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a custom cell and override updateItem to set the color depending on context

Comment: @kleopatra, many  thanks for your comment. I have included in an answer to my own question the SSCCE code snippet updated based on your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **kleopatra** in **2020-09-28 03:30:59Z** comment to the question asked at the top of this page:

> *You need a custom cell and override updateItem to set the color
> depending on context.*

... I created a custom cell (a `ComboBoxTableCell` to be accurate) and overrode its `updateItem` method.

Feel free to re-use it (see source code below) but please pay attention to **kleopatra**'s comment posted for this answer on **2020-09-28 03:30:59Z**:

> *You are probably aware that the logic itself doesn't belong into the
> view (aka: cell) - it should be handled "near" the model, including a
> notification path (vs. hacking around by calling refresh).*

```
public class PersonInRoom extends Application
{
    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob", "Kitchen"),
        new Person("Isabella", "Bedroom"),
        new Person("Ethan", "Attic"));
    TableView<Person> table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        TableColumn nameCol = new TableColumn("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));

        TableColumn roomCol = new TableColumn("Room");
        roomCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("room"));

        roomCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, ComboBoxTableCell<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public ComboBoxTableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> personStringTableColumn)
            {
                String rooms[] = {"Bathroom", "Bedroom", "Kitchen"};
                return new ComboBoxTableCell<>(rooms)
                {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
                    {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!empty) {
                            setText(item);
                            boolean found = false;
                            for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
                                if (rooms[i].equals(item)) {
                                    found = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!found) {
                                setTextFill(Color.RED);
                                return;
                            }
                            int count = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                                if (data.get(i).getRoom().equals(item)) {
                                    if (++count > 1) {
                                        setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                        }
                    }

                };
            }
        });

        roomCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> cellEditEvent)
            {
                cellEditEvent.getTableView().getItems().get(cellEditEvent.getTablePosition().getRow()).setRoom(cellEditEvent.getNewValue());
                table.refresh();
            }
        });


        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, roomCol);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static class Person
    {
        private final SimpleStringProperty name;
        private final SimpleStringProperty room;

        private Person(String name, String room)
        {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.room = new SimpleStringProperty(room);
        }

        public String getName()       {return name.get();}
        public String getRoom()       {return room.get();}
        public void setRoom(String r) {room.set(r);}
    }
}
```

Comment: good starter :) You are probably aware that the logic itself doesn't belong into the view (aka: cell) - it should be handled "near" the model, including a notification path (vs. hacking around by calling refresh).

Comment: @kleopatra, many thanks for your encouragement and additional comment. I have quoted your remark in the body of my answer to make sure it is well understood by potential users of my code snippet.